# Write to a specified Parquet filename in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I am using `SparkR`, and I would like to use `write.df` as a specific folder:

`write.df(my.sdf,path='/path/to/folder/',source='parquet')`

Ideally I'd like to specify a full path name, i.e. `/path/to/folder/this_parquet_file.parquet.gz`

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: No.

You can use `coalesce(1)` to reduce the amount of files inside the parquet folder, but that's it. Writing to output from executors will always result in multiple files because that's how it's designed for scale.